# How to split a string from a file in Java

Tags: java, java-io

I have a line in a file.txt, `|a|b|c|d|`, that I want to extract the values between `|` (result `a,b,c,d`)
How can I do this?

Comment: https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=%22java+read+file+string%22+%22java+split+string%22

Comment: `String[] array =  filecontent.split("|");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pipe (`|`) is a special character in regular expression language (the split method takes a regular expression as a parameter), and thus needs to be escaped.

You will need to use something like so: `String[] str = "|a|b|c|d|".split("\\|");`

Given this:

```
 String[] str = "|a|b|c|d|".split("\\|");
    for(String string : str)
        System.out.println(string);
```

Will yield:

```
  //The first string will be empty, since your string starts with a pipe.
a
b
c
d
```

Comment: only 2 backslash is needed to escape it

Comment: @singhakash: Yes sorry my bad. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

From [String[] split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
>
> The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:
>
> Regex  Result
>       `:  { "boo", "and", "foo" }
>
>   o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }`

Use following code:

```
String[] arr = "|a|b|c|d|".split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File(
            "file.txt"));
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String st;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    st = br.readLine();
    if (st != null) {
        StringTokenizer strTkn = new StringTokenizer(st, "|");
        while (strTkn.hasMoreElements()) {
            sb.append(strTkn.nextElement());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb);

}
```